# How can i create a chess board using buttons where each square has a defined x and y value?

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How can I create buttons on top of this canvas for each square each with their own unique value (starting from (1,1) in the bottom left corner)? I am trying to make a program to play chess with. I need these squares on the canvas to each have a button with a defined coordinate. This also could be changed to just 64 buttons but this is for a program where squares will be highlighted if they have the option to be moved to.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Layout(tk.Tk):
    colours = ["#563a12", "#9f9362"]#square colours dark then light

    def __init__(self, n=8):
        super().__init__()
        self.n = n
        self.leftframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.leftframe.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=10, padx=100)
        self.middleframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.middleframe.grid(row=0, column=8, rowspan=8)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=1200, height=768, )
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=8, rowspan=8)
        self.board = [[None for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]

        self.colourindex = 0



    def changecolours(self):
        self.colourindex = (self.colourindex + 1) % 2

    def drawboard(self):

        for col in range(self.n):
            self.changecolours()
            for row in range(self.n):
                x1 = col * 90
                y1 = (7-row) * 90
                x2 = x1 + 90
                y2 = y1 + 90
                colour = self.colours[self.colourindex] 
                self.board[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=colour)

                self.changecolours()
board = Layout()
board.drawboard()
board.mainloop()
```

Comment: what does your program do, and how is it different from what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want the coordinates of the board tiles. If so you can tag each tile with a unique name and then bind them using `canvas.tag_bind`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Layout(tk.Tk):
    colours = ["#563a12", "#9f9362"]#square colours dark then light

    def __init__(self, n=8):
        super().__init__()
        self.n = n
        self.leftframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.leftframe.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=10, padx=100)
        self.middleframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.middleframe.grid(row=0, column=8, rowspan=8)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=1200, height=768, )
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=8, rowspan=8)
        self.board = [[None for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]

    def drawboard(self):
        from itertools import cycle
        for col in range(self.n):
            color = cycle(self.colours[::-1] if not col % 2 else self.colours)
            for row in range(self.n):
                x1 = col * 90
                y1 = (7-row) * 90
                x2 = x1 + 90
                y2 = y1 + 90
                self.board[row][col] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=next(color), tags=f"tile{col+1}{row+1}")
                self.canvas.tag_bind(f"tile{col+1}{row+1}","<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col+1, j=row+1: self.get_location(e,i,j))

    def get_location(self, event, i, j):
        print (i, j)

board = Layout()
board.drawboard()
board.mainloop()
```